# Objective-C Sectioned UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sections

I want a sectioned UITableView but I don't know how, my situation:

I have 2 arrays

array Date ("12/08/13", "13/08/13", "17/08/13")
array Count("2", "1", "5")

The count means how many rows are there in the section.

I have

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [dateArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

But how can make in the first section, 2 rows in the second section 1 row and in the third section 5 rows.

I hope someone can help me. If you have questions just ask.

Thanks.

EDIT: I get my information from my website so the array changes everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // length of your section count array:
    return [sectionCountArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section            
{
    // the section count from your array, converted to an integer:
    return [sectionCountArray[section] integerValue];
}
```

**UPDATE:** From your comment is seems that you have a "flat" data source array.
Since the row numbers start with zero in each section, you have to compute the
index into the array from the row number and the section count of all previous sections
in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSInteger flatIndex = indexPath.row;
for (NSInteger sec = 0; sec < indexPath.section; sec++)
    flatIndex += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sec];

cell.textLabel.text = yourFlatDataArray[flatIndex]; // (Just an example!)
```

Comment: Thanks it works almost but now I have the same row in every section but when the first section has 2 rows I want the second section counts further so 3 and 4 and not 1 and 2 again. I hope you understand this

Comment: @HenkdeBoer: Then your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not correct. You have to use both `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` to get the element to display. The row number starts with zero in each section.

Answer (score 1):

You return the number of sections in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
      return [self.countArray count];
 }
```

Then get the number from the array and return that in the `numberOfRowsInSection:`

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section            
 {
      NSNumber *count = [self.countArray objectAtIndex:section];

      return [count integerValue];
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the following UITableView datasource method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (section == 0)
    return 2
  else if (section == 1)
    return 1
  else (section == 2)
    return 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get my information from a website so the array is dynamic and changes everyday. So how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: There is already an array that stores the number of rows of every section, you don't need to hardcode it, just return the number taken from this array.